# How do I start the Linux version of Mount & Blade: Warband from GOG in Fedora?

Tags: technical-issues, pc, linux, mount-and-blade-warband, gog

So, I got myself Mount & Blade: Warband from GOG, but when I want to start it, I get something like:

```
error while loading shared libraries: libcurl-gnutls.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I already searched for the Fedora respective version of **libqt5widgets5** and found out it should be:

**qt5-qtbase-gui** and **qt5-qtbase**

How can I start the game?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At first you need to install qt5-qtbase-gui and qt5-qtbase

do that with:

```
sudo dnf install qt5-qtbase-gui
sudo dnf install qt5-qtbase
```

Also make sure you have libcurl installed, if not install that, too.

The solution for:

```
error while loading shared libraries: libcurl-gnutls.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I found [here](https://github.com/ONLYOFFICE/DesktopEditors/issues/158#issuecomment-461399245). So just do:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib64/libcurl.so.4 /usr/lib64/libcurl-gnutls.so.4
```

Comment: This unfortunately doesn't work for me with the steam version and fedora 34. After the symlink the game still crashes on start.

Comment: @jordanm Sorry for the late reply. Hm... but you did install qt5-qtbase-gui and qt5-qtbase? Found here maybe a solution: [link](https://steamcommunity.com/app/48700/discussions/0/522730702080435395/?l=french#c45350245589428992) try to renamethe file 'libgcc_s.so.1' should be located somewhere in your steam folder, here is an example for ubuntu: ~/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/lib/i386-linux-gnu/ if that doesn't solve it, too, then try to start it per terminal and see what error you get ~/.local/share/Steam/steamapps/common/MountBlade\ Warband/mb_warband.sh

Comment: What happens is that it no longer complains about the missing gnutls, but it segfaults. I suspect the latest libcurl is no longer binary compatible with libcurl-gnutls. I ended up just using proton which works fine, but will check out the link. Thanks!